# Spring4 internationalization multiple language

Tags: spring, internationalization, multilingual

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internationalization-example/

Trying to follow this online tutorial to create a multi language web application the problem I am having is that I don't think my spring container is finding / loading my properties files.  I am not sure what is wrong.

File Structure

[image]

welcome.properties

```
welcome.springmvc = Happy learning Spring MVC
```

welcome.properties

```
welcome.springmvc = \u5feb\u4e50\u5b66\u4e60 Spring MVC
```

Index.jsp

```
Language : <a href="?language=en">English</a>|<a href="?language=zh_CN">Chinese</a>

    <h2>
    welcome.springmvc : <spring:message code="welcome.springmvc" text="default text" />
    </h2>

    Current Locale : ${pageContext.response.locale}
```

app-dispatcher-servlet:
I am sure that my interceptors are working because index.jsp ${pageContext.response.locale} is showing en/zh_cn

Internationalization: Multi lang support

Resource:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internationalization-example/
http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internationalization-i18n-and-localization-i10n-example/

http://www.technicalkeeda.com/spring-tutorials/spring-mvc-internationalization-i18n-example

```
<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>

<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="language" />
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>

<!-- <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" >
    <property name="interceptors">
       <list>
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>  -->


<!-- Register the welcome.properties -->
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="welcome" />
</bean>



<!-- ViewResolver JSP -->
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/html/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
```

but my result in index.jsp is

[image]

Where it says "default text" should really show "Happy learning Spring MVC" from the properties files.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Sorry about that I edit my question hope this clear things up. If you look at the last screenshot default text should be "Happy Learning Spring MVC" from the properties files but its showing "default text"

Comment: Eric, Spring MVC is not strong enough to learn. It's just unable to serve you resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my app-dispatcher-servlet.xml explicit state class path

From:

```
<!-- Register the welcome.properties -->
 <bean id="messageSource"
class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
<property name="basename" value="welcome" />
</bean>
```

To:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="com.app.service.CustomMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:com/app/properties/welcome</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />

</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the property file `welcome.properties` to

```
welcome_en_US.properties
```

It should work after that

Comment: can you manually run it in browser like localhost:8080/YourApp/?language=en